# Updating row value for Parse on Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have this code to save data to parse.com cloud on android.

```
NoticeText.put("TheNoticeString", "SampleText");
NoticeText.saveInBackground();
```

How can I update the value for this row ?

Answer (score 0):

Get the object id:

```
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Class Name");        
ParseObject NoticeText = query.get("Row ID");
```

this is the code to update some value:

```
NoticeText.put("TheNoticeString", "SampleTextUpdate");
NoticeText.saveInBackground();
```

if not work check the ACL